# Why I'm getting multiple images on 1 page

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to set a single image as a background image on a page, however, I don't know why it's returning multiple images.

Here is my css code:

```
.servicesHero {
 background-image: url("./images/Resized.jpeg");
 min-height: 60vh;
}
```

Here is my hero component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Hero({children, hero}) {
return (
    <header className={hero}>
        {children}
    </header>
)
}

Hero.defaultProps = {
hero: "defaultHero"
};
```

And here is the call in the services page:

```
import React from 'react'
import Hero from '../Components/Hero'

export default function Services() {
return (
    <Hero hero="servicesHero" />
);
}
```

Here is the result with the repeated image:
[image]

Comment: background-repeat: no-repeat;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apart with the css used you should add the css property to do not repeat background image

```
  .servicesHero {
     background-image: url("./images/Resized.jpeg");
     min-height: 60vh;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

for more references [see](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)